# Using Python to extract segment of numbers from a file?

Tags: python, parsing

I know there are questions on how to extract numbers from a text file, which have helped partially. Here is my problem. I have a text file that looks like:

```
Some crap here: 3434
A couple more lines
of crap.
34 56 56
34 55 55
A bunch more crap here
More crap here: 23
And more: 33
54 545 54
4555 55 55
```

I am trying to write a script that extracts the lines with the three numbers and put them into separate text files. For example, I'd have one file:

```
34 56 56
34 55 55
```

And another file:

```
54 545 54
4555 55 55
```

Right now I have:

```
for line in file_in:
    try:
        float(line[1])
        file_out.write(line)
    except ValueError:
        print "Just using this as placeholder"
```

This successfully puts both chunks of numbers into a single file. But I need it to put one chunk in one file, and another chunk in another file, and I'm lost on how to accomplish this.

Comment: is there something specific separating the numbers? or is it just that groups of numbers need to be grouped into separate files? Also instead of using a `try/except` block, you can use `str.isdigit()` to check if a string is a number or not.

Comment: Nothing specific separating the numbers unfortunately. There might be key phrases in the text that's separating the numbers, though. It's really that the groups of numbers need to be in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a string is a number you can use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
for line in file_in:
    # split line to parts
    parts = line.strip().split()
    # check all parts are numbers
    if all([str.isdigit(part) for part in parts]):
        if should_split:
            split += 1
            with open('split%d' % split, 'a') as f:
                f.write(line)
            # don't split until we skip a line
            should_split = False
        else:
            with open('split%d' % split, 'a') as f:
                f.write(line)
    elif not should_split:
        # skipped line means we should split
        should_split = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what version of Python you were using but you might approach it this way in Python2.7.

[string.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) takes a translation table (which can be None) and a group of characters to translate (or delete if table is None).

You can set your delete_chars to everything but 0-9 and space by slicing `string.printable` correctly:

```
>>> import string
>>> remove_chars = string.printable[10:-6] + string.printable[-4:]
>>> string.translate('Some crap 3434', None, remove_chars)
'  3434'
>>> string.translate('34 45 56', None, remove_chars)
'34 45 56'
```

Adding a `strip` to trim white space on the left and right and iterating over a testfile containing the data from your question:

```
>>> with open('testfile.txt') as testfile:
...   for line in testfile:
...     trans = line.translate(None, remove_chars).strip()
...     if trans:
...       print trans
... 
3434
34 56 56
34 55 55
23
33
54 545 54
4555 55 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex here.But this will require reading file into a variable by `file.read()` or something.(If the file is not huge)

```
((?:(?:\d+ ){2}\d+(?:\n|$))+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/20

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'((?:(?:\d+ ){2}\d+(?:\n|$))+)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "Some crap here: 3434\nA couple more lines\nof crap.\n34 56 56\n34 55 55\nA bunch more crap here\nMore crap here: 23\nAnd more: 33\n54 545 54\n4555 55 55"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

`re.findall` returns a list.You can easily put each content of list in a new file.